# How to create a language translator from scratch?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, rnn, machine-translation, nlg

I want to create a translator which can translate English, Korean and Tamil sentences into English sentence, I tried googletrans but is there any way to create something better than that using DL and NLP techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Google translate itself uses Deep learning to translate sentences which can be seen [here](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub45610).

You can translate sentences across languages for which you need two things :

1. A large dataset which has pairs of translations ( like English-French ). You can find such a dataset from [here](http://www.manythings.org/anki/).
2. A sequence-to-sequence RNN model. They have Encoder-Decoder architecture which encodes the source sentence into a thought vector and then decode it to form the translation. This image may be helpful.
   [image]
   The picture shows the [Neural Machine Translation](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/nmt_with_attention) adopted by Google.

Also, TensorFlow and Keras help in creating such deep learning models. You can refer to [this](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) blog from the author of Keras. These models ( seq2seq ) have gained popularity in text summarization, NMT, and other sequence-to-sequence tasks.

If you wish to create a full-scale production ready language translator then you will need a GPU as these models are heavy to train as well as a very large corpus of text.